# VBA counting error when using lookuprange command

Tags: excel, vba, count, vlookup, lookup

```
Dim endweek As Long
Dim lookuprange As Range
Dim resultrange As Range
Dim resultcell As Range
Dim weeknumber As Long
Dim counter As Long

Sub updategraphs()
    startweek = InputBox("Specify the beginning range of the weeks you wish to graph (numbers only):", "Beginning Week Range?")
   
    If Not IsNumeric(startweek) Then
        MsgBox "Error, please input data using a number-only format.", vbOKOnly, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    startweek = CLng(startweek)
    endweek = startweek + 6
   
    Set lookuprange = Worksheets("FY2023").Range("A3:BT62")
    Set resultrange = Worksheets("W2W").Range("A2:A8")
   
    For Each resultcell In resultrange
        weeknumber = startweek + (resultcell.Row - resultrange.Row)
       
        Dim foundCell As Range
        Set foundCell = lookuprange.Columns(1).Find(weeknumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
       
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            resultcell.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        Else
            resultcell.Value = "Week Not Found"
        End If
    Next resultcell
End Sub
```

Basically, I originally tried to do a vlookup function, which also had the same error.
I've tried to do a count loop to fix the issue, but this has not worked either.
the code works but instead of pulling the week numbers in sequential order (1, 2, 3, 4,..7) it adds four after the first one to every subsequent loop: (1, 5, 9, 13, 17.. 25) until reaching 7 loops and terminating. My main question is how do I get it to not count up like that? I'm literally just pulling year numbers from one worksheet and putting them in a location on another worksheet

Comment: Btw `resultrange.Row` always equals 2. Is that way you wanted?

Comment: omg i think you're right